# Error SSL/TLS connection in MQTT with mosquitto broker

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to use a SSL/TLS encryption connection with openssl between a raspberry and the mosquitto broker. To do so, I have entered the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 2000 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -out server.csr -key server.key
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 410
```

Then I have move the ca_certificates folder under /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates and also  the server certificate and key in the /etc/mosquitto/certs folder.

Now, I try to `mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf -v` it gives me:

```
1653586436: The 'port' option is now deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use 'listener' instead.
1653586436: mosquitto version 2.0.12 starting
1653586436: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1653586436: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1653586436: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1653586436: Error: Unable to load CA certificates. Check cafile "c:\etc\mosquitto\ca_certificates\ca.crt".
1653586436: Error: Unable to load server certificate "c:\etc\mosquitto\certs\server.crt". Check certfile.
1653586436: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
1653586436: OpenSSL Error[1]: error:20074002:BIO routines:file_ctrl:system lib
1653586436: OpenSSL Error[2]: error:140DC002:SSL routines:use_certificate_chain_file:system lib
```

What I have in the `mosquitto.conf` is:

```
port 8883
cafile c:\etc\mosquitto\ca_certificates\ca.crt
certfile c:\etc\mosquitto\certs\server.crt
keyfile c:\etc\mosquitto\certs\server.key
```

Do you have any idea of where is my error?

Comment: First problem (`mosquitto_pub`) is probably the wrong port number, but without detail how how you configured mosquitto no more can be said. Second problem implies that the CA certificate you have passed to the python is not the one that signed the broker's certificate or some other configuration issue, but again without the code it's impossible to say more. A Stack Overflow question should only contain one problem at a time, pick one and edit the question to cover just that one.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Let me know if with this information is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved the issue.The problem was that mosquitto was not capable of reading the files not because of permission issues but because of the filepaths.

So the thing was that when defining the filepaths in the mosquitto.conf I had to use:

```
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
```

Instead of:

```
cafile c:\etc\mosquitto\ca_certificates\ca.crt
certfile c:\etc\mosquitto\certs\server.crt
keyfile c:\etc\mosquitto\certs\server.key
```

Answer (score 1):

`mosquitto_pub`'s default port is 1883, you have configured mosquitto to use port 8883

The correct command line is

```
mosquitto_pub --cafile ca.crt -h localhost -p 8883 -t Value -m 2
```

As it is this isn't even getting to any SSL stuff

Comment: I still have the error of connection refused.

Comment: Then mosquitto is not using the config file you have posted. Edit the question to explain exactly how you are starting it and the log output

Comment: It was but I have just erase some commands that I had and that when doing mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf -v gave me errors